# Is it ever worse to add more rounds?

Tags: encryption, aes

As my understanding goes, it is generally more secure to add more rounds to an algorithm (though it may increase processing time). Is there any exceptions to this rule? Theoretically - if your processor could handle it - could you run AES, but with 8 additional rounds, dramatically increasing the security? With what algorithm(s)/methods does this not apply and why?

Comment: Adding a round to ROT13 is clearly a bad idea...

Comment: It depends of the cipher you consider, and might have sliding attacks ...

Comment: TL;DR: Yes, details in: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/484

Comment: @SEJPM From the abstract it's not clear to me if they're talking about a reduction in security, or just about attack cost not scaling linearly with the number of rounds (and thus cost).

Comment: @CodesInChaos _"However, after performing a thorough literature study on the cryptanalysis of non-ideal primitives, it appears to be a little-known fact that for certain constructions, the complexity of a cryptanalysis resu lt can decrease when the number of rounds of the primitive is increased."_ and _"when the number of rounds of the primitive is increased, the complexity of the cryptanalysis result decreases."_

Comment: Also trivial theoretical example: Hash a value twice. Theoretically your chances of a collision go up by this because now you need to consider collisions on the first input and on the second input.

Comment: @SEJPM Yet your example doesn't decrease the cost of finding a collision in absolute terms. The work factor only decreases because you redefined the base line to be twice as expensive. So this kind of weakening only applies if you're limited by oracle queries, not when you're limited by computational cost.